# Using VHDL to generate many parallel processing unit

Tags: image-processing, parallel-processing, vhdl

Each unit will produce 1 pixel and the total 200m+ units will generate a picture. So each unit will have their own place to store the input(matrices), and the results form each unit will be saved in a single matrix.

Should I just use for-generate to done this? or by other ways?

Comment: How *big* is one unit? What's the target platform?

Comment: Try adding some of the code you have already done for this or a prototype that would give all of us an idea of your progress so we can contribute better

Comment: Is this a purely theoretical exercise? Or are you actually targeting real hardware? For the former then for-generate will be fine you'll just end up with very, very wide buses. If the later and you are targeting an FPGA - it needs a re-think. The top ultrascale devices have 3.5m flip-flops and they are massive devices. You have to think about how quickly you need to produce a picture, what the resolution is, what calculation is each unit doing and how fast can you clock each cell. Then you have to scale appropriately for the application.

Comment: @sv65536 I'm targeting on real hardware, so maybe I should found some other way, but I still need to generate quite a bit of processing unit. are there any other way? except for-generatel

Comment: Without knowing the application it's difficult to give you an idea of the best way to deal with it. As a VHDL language question, the generate statement is pretty much the best way to replicate instantiations and you can use indexed arrays of signals, or very wide buses with calculations to work out the index range for each instantiation. Work out what the calculation is, how you would pipeline a single unit to do the work and then think about how many parallel units you would need but keep in mind what device you could be targeting. That large ultrascale device I mentioned is $20,000.

Answer (score 0):

For a lot of instances, create one general entity with generics and then on the top level use the for-loop generates like you said in your question. Use the generics in the for-loop to set index numbers etc.